# Get active term on single (CPT) page

Tags: single

I know similar questions have been asked here but I feel my case is slightly different.

I need to get the *active* *current* term (object) on a CPT single page. However, the single post can have multiple categories. This means *I can't just get all the post terms* and array pop the first index (because this is not always the currently active term).

Say for example I have an url like: mysite.com/my-cpt/my-custom-term/my-cpt-post

Now on the my-cpt-post template I need to get the  "my-custom-term" object.

Thanx for the help.

Comment: There is no such thing as a current (active) term on a single post page.

Comment: Hi Pieter,true, but in the url structure there will be a term (lets call that one the "active" term). I would like to get the object of that term.

Comment: think breadcrumbs

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. Take a read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.25category.25_with_multiple_categories_on_a_post)

Comment: Ok, but isn't this a very basic situation? I have menu item with a list of CPT terms as a submenu. The cpt posts are not listed in the menu. Now, on the single cpt page I want a breadcrumb path which should of course include the category. This can't be done? (other then retrieving the term slug via REQUST_URI or something). That's odd!